# Переменная в командной строке

Tags: bat

Как правильно присваивать значение переменной в батнике, пытаюсь таким образом.

```
set /p input = Enter int
echo %input%
IF "%input%" == 1 (
   cd bh && mvn clean package)
```

Выдает в командной строке

```
C:\Users\s>set /p input = Enter chislo
Enter int1
C:\Users\s>echo
Режим вывода команд на экран (ECHO) включен.
C:\Users\s>IF "" == 1 (cd bh   && mvn clean package )
```

пробовал без ковычек использовать переменную, такой же результат, что не правильно делаю?

Comment: set /p input= Enter int пробел перед "="
echo %input%
IF %input% == 1 (echo ok) кавычки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас стоит пробел перед знаком равенства. В итоге команда set создает переменную с именем "`input`" (обратите внимание на пробел в конце).

Comment: ага, работает,спасибо